# Why does the first request to any stack site take unusually long within a given time frame?

Tags: discussion, page-load, connectivity

Example: I'm sitting in Austria, Europa. My #1 way to visit e.g. stackoverflow or superuser etc. is by going to Google and, due it's programming related query, usually pops me up a link to stackoverflow.

When it is the first time in the morning or afternoon, the first opening of the page takes unusually long, I'm talking here about 10 seconds or even longer.

When I go back to Google, click on the link again, it's there like in <1s.

When I cancel the page load (I'm inpatient) and hit refresh, I usually get it in around 5s.

Once I'm *through*, every other request just gets served as quickly as <1s, as one would expect.

Is there some kind of warm up for overseas connection?

I've noticed this over the last half year minimum. I.e. I'm already expected the first page access to take annoying long to the point I do not wait for it, cancel the operation, try to load again, etc.

FYI, I've never seen this with other pages which I know are located somewhere in the US.

I'm seeing this with FF (always latest version, so it's FF12 right now). I never clear my cache manually. I visit stack site related pages (SO, SU, etc.) definitely on a daily basis.

Comment: The second time, it's probably cached. That explains why it's < 1 second. But over 10 seconds to load the first time? I've never seen that.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Having lived in both the US and India, I can certify that internet speeds have a huge difference (your lowest tier five years ago is still not available here). On certain days, SO could take 10s to load over here. Not usually, though :)

Comment: @Manishearth: what is important to note, I am only (!) talking about the first-visit experience. Once I was there and, say, visit SO once in a while over the day, I never see this again. But when I'm going to be a way a few more hours and come back, the first initial load again looks like it's hanging. Sure, typical Cache pattern I guess, but looks like it could be improved regarding timeout .. if this is all the case, anyway.

Comment: I take it back. I saw that > 10 seconds *just today* while trying to browse the site on my iPwn. Stupid AT&T...